# Referencing an element drawn in the main App

Tags: javascript, rally, appsdk2

I am writing a Rally App in which I have a rallychart and a button.
I need to access the chart and modify its setting on a button click. The button is also in the  same app container as the rallychart.

I tried Ext. this. etc. 
These access specifiers do not work. Could you please help me with this?

Sample code:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    id: 'appid',
    launch: function () {

        var datepickerfrom = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'rallytextfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Enter Start Date for chart (mm/dd/yyyy): ',
                labelWidth: 150
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody().dom,
            id: 'd1'
        });

        this.add(datepickerfrom);
        this.add(
                {
                     xtype: 'rallychart',
                    height: 400,
                    width: 800,
                    id: 'chart1',
                    itemId: 'chart1',
                    chartConfig: chartConfig,
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody().dom
                }
            );

button2 = {
            xtype: 'rallybutton',
            text: 'Plot Graph',
            handler: function () {
                console.clear();
                console.log("Clicking button");
     // I NEED to ACCESS the CHART HERE or EVEN the TEXTFIELD DATA HERE 

            },
            callback: function(){

            }
        };

this.add(button2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may reference them via itemID. After the itemID on the element is set:

```
 this.add(
     {
         xtype: 'rallychart',
         height: 400,
         itemId: 'myChart',
         chartConfig: {//...}
//...
}
```

it can be used to reference the element:

```
this.down('#myChart')
```

Comment: You can also just add it as an id, can you not?  Only then it would have to be unique?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Nick said (referencing by id) you can create a variable for each one as you define them like so:

```
var pickerForm = this.add(datepickerfrom);
var chart = this.add({
    xtype: 'rallychart',
    height: 400,
    width: 800,
    id: 'chart1',
    itemId: 'chart1',
    chartConfig: chartConfig,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody().dom
});
```

And then reference them like this:

```
chart.method1();
...
```

Here is an example application.  The toggle button shows and hides the cardboard:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text : 'Toggle Cardboard',
        handler: function() {
            if (App.cardBoard.isHidden()) {
                App.cardBoard.show();
            } else {
                App.cardBoard.hide();
            }
        }
    }],

    launch: function() {
        App = this;
        var addNewConfig = {
            xtype: 'rallyaddnew',
            recordTypes: ['PortfolioItem/Feature', 'PortfolioItem/Initiative', 'PortfolioItem/Theme'],
            ignoredRequiredFields: ['Name', 'Project'],
            showAddWithDetails: false
        };

        App.addNew = this.add(addNewConfig);

        var cardBoardConfig = {
            xtype: 'rallycardboard',
            types: ['PortfolioItem/Feature', 'PortfolioItem/Rollup'],
            attribute: 'InvestmentCategory'
        };

        App.cardBoard = this.add(cardBoardConfig);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried setting a variable.

    var datepickerfrom = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    items: [{
            xtype: 'rallytextfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Enter Start Date for chart (mm/dd/yyyy): ',
            labelWidth: 150
    }],
                renderTo: Ext.getBody().dom,
                id: 'd1'
            });

            var dpf = this.add(datepickerfrom);


and then using it as dpf.getValue() in the fun
But i get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getValue'

when i try ot access it in the action of the button click as specified above

Comment: instead of `dpf.getValue()`, have you tried `datepickerform.getValue()`?

Comment: take out the renderTo option - when you call this.add, you are telling it to add it to the app.  If that doesn't work, you might want to try doing it Nick's way, which is the other way to do it `App.down('myChart').getValue()`

Comment: and it definitely works for me doing `App.grid = App.down('#displayArea').add({...});` and then calling methods like `App.grid.isHidden()`